# How to access a property of a generic class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm creating an API that connects to a Mongo database.

After creating the methods of the repository that update certain fields of a collection, I thought that maybe I could refactor the code, because the following structure repeated itself many times:

```
var filter = Builders<Server>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, objectUpdated.Id);
var update = Builders<Server>.Update.Set(x=> x.SomeProperty, objectUpdated.SomeProperty);
```

I've thought about creating a method somewhat like this:

```
public static void Update<T>(ObjectId id, Property property)
{
  var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
  var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(x=> x.property, property);
}
```

But I don't know how could I get the property as a parameter and how to compare the `Id` property in the filter, because I'm dealing with a generic class, so I would get the following error:

> CS1061: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no accessible
> extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [constrain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) `T` to some type which has `Id` property. Usually it is done via interfaces. For example something like this:

```cs
public interface IHaveId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public static void Update<T>(ObjectId id, Property property) where T : IHaveId
{
  var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, objectUpdated.Id);
  var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(x=> x.property, objectUpdated.property);
}
```